# Spring-HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [￞] is not a hexadecimal digit

Tags: java, spring

I am Encrypting a huge data file and the same data needs to be passed to my 'inserData' method, But when i pass the encrypted data(user.getEiddata()) to inserData method I am getting- "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [￞] is not a hexadecimal digit"
What is the proper datatype needs to be used when we are forwarding request?
Please find my below code:

```
CryptoUtilsController.java:
-----------------------------
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CryptoUtilsController {
     @Autowired  
     UserService userService;  

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String encryptData(ModelMap model) {
         String key = "John has one cat";
         File inputFile = new File("D:\\Other_Project_Codebase\\EncryptionDemo\\document.json");
         File encryptedFile = new File("D:\\Other_Project_Codebase\\EncryptionDemo\\document.encrypted");

         User user = null;
        try {
            CryptoUtils cryptoUtils = new CryptoUtils();
            user = cryptoUtils.encrypt(key, inputFile, encryptedFile);
            System.out.println("eiddata:: "+user.getEiddata());
            System.out.println("randomkey:: "+user.getRandomkey());
         } catch (CryptoException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception in encryptData");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         return "forward:/insert?eiddata="+user.getEiddata()+"&randomkey="+user.getRandomkey();  
       }

     @RequestMapping("/insert")  
     public String inserData(@RequestParam String eiddata, @RequestParam String randomkey) {  
        User user = new User();
        user.setEiddata(eiddata);
        user.setRandomkey(randomkey);
      if (user != null)  {
          userService.insertData(user);  
      }
      return "hello";
     } 
}
```

### CryptoUtils.java:

```
public class CryptoUtils {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

    public User encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        User user = doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
        return user;
    }

    private User doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile,
            File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        try {
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);

            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            //Added
            String eidData = null;
            String randomKey = null;
            User user = new User();
            try{
             DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (new FileInputStream (outputFile));

             byte[] datainBytes = new byte[dis.available()];
             dis.readFully(datainBytes);
             dis.close();

             eidData = new String(datainBytes, 0, datainBytes.length);
             randomKey =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();  

             user.setEiddata(eidData);
             user.setRandomkey(randomKey);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //End

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            return user;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex);
        }
    }
}

Exception Trace:
-----------------
Feb 25, 2016 12:40:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [?] is not a hexadecimal digit
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.convertHexDigit(RequestUtil.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.parseParameters(RequestUtil.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.parseParameters(RequestUtil.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.mergeParameters(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:894)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.parseParameters(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getParameterValues(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.getParameterValues(ServletWebRequest.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Can you tel me how to pass the encrypted data to insertData method, without getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

1. Please add [spring-security-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE) as a dependency in your POM.xml
2. You should use **PasswordEncoder** interface from spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar to process your hexadecimal digit.
3. Please refer this [StandardPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) will be suited for your case and also please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479116/how-to-use-spring-standardpasswordencode-and-get-salt-generate) which will add more help to you.
4. This [reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) also will help you.

Comment: @Raedwald: Can you please suggest what should i do to solve the above exception?

Comment: @Thej, Can you please share your CryptoUtils.java ?

Comment: @Thej, Also Can you please share your User.java? Need to know about the encrypting parameters you are setting

Comment: public class User {

 private String eiddata;
 private String randomkey;
 
 public String getEiddata() {
  return eiddata;
 }
 public void setEiddata(String eiddata) {
  this.eiddata = eiddata;
 }
 public String getRandomkey() {
  return randomkey;
 }
 public void setRandomkey(String randomkey) {
  this.randomkey = randomkey;
 }
 
}