# Migration of spring-security-core 3.2.4-RELEASE to spring-security-core 5.8.6. Facing issues with password encoding

Tags: java, spring-security, upgrade, sha, password-encryption

[I am getting this error on ant build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4cO.png) 
This is my existing code -->

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;

public static String encodePassword(String password, String salt) {

        byte[] unencodedPassword = password.getBytes();
       ShaPasswordEncoder encoder=new ShaPasswordEncoder();
       String  encodedPwd= encoder.encodePassword(password,null);
       encodedPwd = encoder.encodePassword(encodedPwd,salt);
       return encodedPwd;
}
 public static String changeEncodedPassword(String password, String salt) {
       ShaPasswordEncoder encoder=new ShaPasswordEncoder();
       
       String encodedPwd = encoder.encodePassword(password,salt);
       
       return encodedPwd;
     }
 public static String encodSH2Password(String password, String salt) {
         ShaPasswordEncoder encoder=new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
         
         String encodedPwd = encoder.encodePassword(password,salt);
         
         return encodedPwd;
       }
```

Now, ShaPasswordEncoder has been deprecated in 5.8.6 jar

So, I searched through the internet and I found DelegatingPasswordEncoder should be used and an additional jar i.e. spring-security-crypto is to be imported. So, I wrote the following statement to change the encoding from previous version to recent one.

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

 public static String encodePass() {
         
         String idForEncode = "sha256";
         Map <String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
         encoders.put("sha256", new StandardPasswordEncoder());
         PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
        return idForEncode;

     }
```

Since we have used salt value in case of ShaPasswordEncoder but we can't use that in DelegatingPasswordEncoder ,so I want to know an approach how to write the migration code from previous version to new one.
Also, this StandardPasswordEncoder has been deprecated so what alternative should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer in that post:

[How to use Spring StandardPasswordEncode and Get Salt Generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479116/how-to-use-spring-standardpasswordencode-and-get-salt-generate)

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
    byte[] digested = decode(encodedPassword);
    byte[] salt = subArray(digested, 0, saltGenerator.getKeyLength());
    return matches(digested, digest(rawPassword, salt));
}
```

This is not very clear in documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html :

> The digest algorithm is invoked on the concatenated bytes of the salt, secret and password.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `ShaPasswordEncoder` is replaced by `LdapShaPasswordEncoder`. Think you can simply replace to use it to have a quick fix on your build problem.

But using `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` to encode password is considered to be insecure. Although there is no plan it will be removed based on its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/LdapShaPasswordEncoder.html), it is recommended to migrate using a more secure encoder such as bcrypt for encoding new users' password and also think a strategy to migrate the existing users' password to encode with this more secure encoder.

[`DelegatingPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage-dpe) is designed to facilitate such migration. For example if you use :

```java
Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
encoders.put("SSHA", new LdapShaPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
PasswordEncoder  passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
```

Then the first parameter of `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` 's constructor means it will use `BCryptPasswordEncoder`  to encode the password for the new users.  For matching to see if the provided password matched with the existing password (e.g. during login) , it will use `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` to decode the existing password if the password starts with the prefix `{SSHA}` which should be if you use `ShaPasswordEncoder` or `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` to encode it.

For the migration strategy of migrating the existing user to use a more secure password encoder,  you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240744/spring-security-3-1-4-and-shapasswordencoder-deprecation) for some ideas.